# adding a new attribute and assigning the value of the class name to it - jQuery

Tags: jquery

I have a scenario where I need to keep track of class names before I change them to something else. I am planning to add a new attribute to the elements and assign the class name to it. How can I achieve this?

This is the element

```
<td id = "tds1" class="myclass" ></td>
```

I am trying something like this.

```
$("#tds1").attr("baseClassName": function () {
    var classname = $(this).class;
    return classname + "base";
});
```

I need the element to be formed like this

```
<td id = "tds1" class="myclass" baseclassName="myclassbase" ></td>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A somewhat terse option:

```
$('#tds1').attr('baseclassname', function() {
  return $(this).attr('class') + 'base';
});
```

Using the jQuery $(...) notation will create a jQuery object, meaning you'll need use a jQuery method (in this case, .attr()) to get at the class value.

Hope that helps...

Answer (score 2):

You're fairly close. The correct code would look like this:

```
$('#tds1').attr('baseClassName', function() {
    var classname = this.className;

    return classname + 'base';
});
```

The changes:

- Use `this` rather than `$(this)`.  The former is a DOM object; the latter is a jQuery object The DOM object can do everything we need it to do.
- Use `this.className` to get  the `class` attribute. Note the capital `N` and the fact that we're getting the property of the DOM object not the jQuery selection.

Otherwise, this is definitely the right way to approach this. The one question I have is whether it's *necessary*. It may be that `jQuery.fn.data` does what you need, or indeed possibly another function. I can't see why you'd essentially want to duplicate information in the element's attributes.